# Specific tiling for washing machine closet?

Tags: washing-machine, sound-proofing, tiling, uk

I am planing to **install a washing machine in a closet**. There is currently a fitted carpet in this ca. 2 m² closet. 
To avert consequences a plausible leak/overflow, I want to **replace the fitted carpet with tiling**.

I am concerned about both the mechanical stress to the tiling and the noise (both for us and my downstairs neighbours) generated by the vibration of the washing machine.

***Is there something specific I can/should do before or during the tiling** (knowing I will install a washing machine on it)**?***

(One restriction is the choice of the tiles themselves, as I plan to use the remainder of another project.)

---

<sub>Note: I have never done any tiling before, nor am a specifically experienced DIYer — so please excuse the probably naive question. (Nonetheless, I believe I haven't two left feet nor half a brain only, so I should be able to get through the tiling.)</sub>

Comment: Put rubber pads between the feet of the washer and the tiles - which is an "after tiling, in the normal way" approach to noise/vibration. If you **don't have a floor drain**, tile will help only a small amount in the case of a "plausible leak/overflow."

Comment: I won't have a floor drain in the closet indeed, as I'm living in a flat where it's not possible to install one. In addition, I have to evacuate the grey water through the ceiling (not the ideal, yet the only possible solution I'm afraid), via a solution similar to [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/28415/90042) (I'll let the plumbing be done by a professional, as — as it's said in the question — it's carrying around a loaded mouse trap; yet it's the price to pay to get a dishwasher).

Comment: Also, you can put a washing machine pan under the washing machine. This won't help with big leaks, but will catch some water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ecnerwal rubber pads would be best. We are a diy site and here to help you. 
Other things

I prefer to use a concrete backer board screwed down to the flooring to mount tile to. Never put tile directly on chip board , OSB or most underlayments. Plywood will work but the others when wet come apart as the tile can allow moisture and then it becomes a real mess.

Pick a tile you like because it can last your lifetime and I think most new to tile do better with larger sizes. I have seen many first timers try 2x2 because they are on a sheet and it usually looks diy. Larger tiles and spend the few bucks for spacers and use them.

Watch some on line videos so you understand how to “set” the tile using a notched trowel.

Starting with a small space like a laundry closet is a great way to get experience , remove existing mop or trim boards. Put your backer down and go for it, good luck!

Comment: Also,  think about using epoxy grout as it's much more durable than regular grout and it's waterproof.  It's a little harder to work with but take your time and follow the directions.+

Comment: Yes epoxy grout is better for flexibility and sealing. I think flex sounds funny on tile but it is a good product good advice @jack.

Comment: The floor I want to tile seems to be some [quite porous concrete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RlLl.jpg). Should I consider to put some sort of waterproof film/coating beforehand?

Comment: Many people do but in an area that is not normally wet I would save the $. Even if some water got through it won’t hurt the concrete so I see no advantage , I regularly etch slabs if there is any wax or glue , but yours looks clean I would mop it to clean any dust and lint and use thinset to lay the tile directly to the concrete.